# Castle Windsor does not release transient component consistently

Tags: c#, mvvm, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm creating an WPF application with MVVM pattern and Castle Windsor as IoC container. Problem is that windsor seams to inconsistently releases my components.

I've got the following components:

- TypedFactory for Views
- MainView (Transient) + MainViewModel (Transient)
- ViewA (Transient) + ViewModelA (Transient)
- ViewB (Transient) + ViewModelB (Transient)
- DataServiceA (Singleton)
- DataServiceB (Singleton)

DependencyGraph is:

- MainView -> MainViewModel -> DataServiceA, DataServiceB
- ViewA -> ViewModelA -> DataServiceA
- ViewB -> ViewModelB -> DataServiceB

DataServices are used to communicate between the ViewModels and therefore must be singleton. MainView is mainly switching between the two views by resolving one from the factory while releasing the other one.
ViewModels are inserted through PropertyInjection in code-behind of the view.

I subscribed to the events Container.Kernel.ComponentCreated and ComponentDestroyed to see if the tracking works correctly.

Problem is, ViewModelA is destroyed when ViewA is released, but ViewModelB isn't the same way. From my perspective, the two ViewModels should be treated equally because the only difference is the dependency.